# Gimp fuzzy selector selection not being removed on delete

Tags: gimp, linux

I've done this precise thing before, but for some reason after selecting with the fuzzy selector the portion of the image I want to remove and hitting the delete key, it's not being removed.. Am I in some kind of weird mode? I am able to copy the selection but not cut it. I can fill it but erase it.. Any ideas?

Comment: so strange. I reopened to try what you are saying and it's just working as usual now.. If you answer the question I'll give you the points because that was good thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A guess: Your layer has no alpha channel(=no transparency possible) and you try to delete a part which already has the background color. Insert the alpha channel. It works if your color mode is RGB.